# Core Data class and fetch request issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I'm puzzled by an error using Core Data (XCode 7.1 / Swift 2.0)

The below code is working perfectly

```
class DB_PlayerData: NSManagedObject
{
    @NSManaged var playerID: NSNumber
}

class PlayerClass
{
    var IDPlayer: Int = 0
}

func test()
{
    let LocalAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let ManagedObjectContext = LocalAppDelegate.managedObjectContext
    var SelectAll = NSFetchRequest()
    var ResultatRecherche: NSArray = []
    var gPlayerData = PlayerClass()


    SelectAll = NSFetchRequest(entityName: eNomDBFiles.DB_PlayerData.rawValue)
    try! ResultatRecherche = ManagedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(SelectAll) as! [DB_PlayerData]
    if (ResultatRecherche.count == 1)
    {
        gPlayerData.IDPlayer = Int(ResultatRecherche[0].playerID)
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But if the function `test` is not in the same swift file in my project as the `DB_PlayerData` class declaration, I get the following error: `Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'playerID'`

Entity has been created in the DB model in Xcode with name and class equal to `DB_PlayerData` and Module set to project name. I've tried all kind of setup options described here and there was no success.

Any clue why?

Comment: Note that it is good practice to start each variable name with a lowercase letter, and each word after starting with an uppercase. For example, instead of `ResultatRecherche`, it would be `resultatRecherche`. This is known as lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent told the compiler which type is enclosed in your array.

```
    var ResultatRecherche: [DB_PlayerData] = []
```

instead of

```
    var ResultatRecherche: NSArray = []
```

I suggest you always try to use the correct swift type instead of the foundation types such as NSArray. If you absolutely must use `NSArray`, you need to cast `ResultatRecherche[0]` to the correct type before trying to access a property, otherwise it will have the type of AnyObject.

Comment: When I put `try! ResultatRecherche = ManagedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(SelectAll) as! [DB_PlayerData]` I'm indicating the type of the array, and I do it before accessing the property. Or did I miss something somewhere ?

Comment: Even though, `ResultatRecherche` is still a type of its superclass NSArray, which the compiler doesnt know what it actually contains.

Comment: Your solution actually works. Thanks even if I still don't get the logic of it.